# TimePickerDialog установка текущего времени

Tags: android, kotlin

При первом запуске установка текущего времени в элементе TimePickerDialog происходит нормально. Но, если попытаться обновить время

> timePickerDialog.updateTime(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
>   calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE))

ничего не получается. Время в **TimePickerDialog** остается таким, как при первом запуске. Может, кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/activity_main"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:text="Time"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
  android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"/>

 <Button
  android:id="@+id/button2"
  android:text="Clear"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
  android:layout_marginStart="4dp"/>

 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView1"
  android:layout_width="150dp"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:text=""
  android:textSize="26sp"
  android:textColor="#ffffff"
  android:gravity="center"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

***MainActivity.kt***

```
package ru.site.a1

import android.app.TimePickerDialog
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

 private lateinit var timePickerDialog: TimePickerDialog
 private var calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
 private var h: String = ""
 private var m: String = ""

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

  //кнопка TIME запускает диалоговое окно
  button1.setOnClickListener {
   //context - this
   //событие TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener
   //текущее время - час
   //текущее время - минута
   //true — 24 часовой формат, false — 12 часовой формат
   timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(
    this,
    //событие выбора времени в элементе TimePickerDialog
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { view, hourOfDay, minute ->

     if (hourOfDay < 10) {
      h = "0$hourOfDay"
     } else {
      h = "$hourOfDay"
     }

     if (minute < 10) {
      m = "0$minute"
     } else {
      m = "$minute"
     }

     textView1.text = "$h : $m"
     textView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d81b60"))
    },
    calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
    calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
    true
   )

   timePickerDialog.show()
  }

  //кнопка CLEAR
  button2.setOnClickListener {
   textView1.text = ""
   textView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"))
   //установка текущего времени в элементе TimePickerDialog
   timePickerDialog.updateTime(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: у меня есть код для DatePickerDialog на java. если хочешь могу скинуть

Comment: Уважаемый Yury Matatov! Спасибо, не нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Вы создаете новый объект TimePickerDialog каждый раз когда нажимаете на кнопку 1 (при нажатии кнопки 2 время в объекте меняется, но при повторном нажатии на кнопку 1 это уже будет новый объект). Как вариант объявить атрибут класса TimePickerDialog dialog, и создать объект в методе onCreate.